# can't shrink more than 100MB but there is 350GB free space

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have 1TB drive and 350GB free and I try to shrink the 350GB free using the disk manage in windows 10 settings but it is only allow me to shrink 100MB, how to fix it ?

Comment: What is the console view of disk managment ? how do I access it ?

Comment: CMD version of diskmanagement is `diskpart`. The commands: `list disk`, `select disk #` `list volume`, `list partition`

Answer (score 2):

Windows Disk Administrator can only shrink a filesystem if there is unused space at the end. (It truncates the unused blocks from the end.)
It seems that you only have 100 MB of unused space at the end. The rest of the 350 GB is probably spread over the rest of the disk.

Try a defrag first. This will hopefully move files from the end of the filesystem forward, allowing for more reduction.

If that doesn't give satisfactory results you need a 3rd party partitioning utility that can re-organize the filesystem contents and do the re-size for you.

EaseUs Partition Master (free edition) is probably easiest to use for a novice.
GPartEd is another good one, but it is Linux based and needs a USB boot-stick to start from, which may complicate things.

There are many other tools out there. For specific question about such tools I like to refer you to our sister site [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)